# How do I get distinct value in one row and their respective average values as output in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have **a mySQL table with 100 rows and 6 columns** namely ; *full_name, name, score, city, gender, rating*. I want the output as **one column containing distinct city values** (there are only 5 distinct cities **initially** & the user input value of his/her city will be added, namely; *Delhi, Mumbai, Patna, Chennai ,Pune*) and the **second column having their respective avg score**.

The database is linked to the python code which I am working on & use takes input which is stored in the above 6 columns. Then according to the user request, the output as analysis is showed as graphs using matplotlib. But I am really stuck at this part where I need to show a graph having X-VALUES as city names and Y-VALUES as respective avg score for that, I need to know the query to get such an output in mySQL where we get 2 columns storing the above.

**How do I do it ?**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT city AS X,AVG(score) AS Y
FROM yourtable GROUP BY city
```

Is this, what you ment? Or if you want the result as one row, you add GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(X) AS gX,GROUP_CONCAT(Y) AS gY FROM
(SELECT city AS X,AVG(score) AS Y
    FROM yourtable GROUP BY city) g
```

Comment: Thanks , that's really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

ok, redbull helps...

**correct syntax :**

```
select city, avg(score) from data group by city;
```

---

**wrong syntax (what I was trying to do earlier) :**

```
select data.distinct(city), data.avg(score) , check.check_city from data, (select name, distinct(city) as check_city from data) check where data.name = check.name and data.city in check.check_city;
```

**Thanks Anyway !**